# Firebase prevent connection with Email and Password login with Google login

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I already have implemented the Google login and the Email and Password login. When someone signs up with email and password then afterwards logs in with google the accounts are then connected together like this:[image]

So my question is how to prevent connecting an already existing email and password account with google?

Comment: And what's the question?

Comment: @AlexMamo was in a hurry, forgot to add the actual question, sorry :p

Comment: Why would you want to prevent? This is a feature not a problem.

Comment: Because I don't want any 3rd partys connect to a users email adress? I don't care if it's meant as a feature.

Comment: In that case, why have you enabled Google autentication?

Comment: Because if someone wants to register himself with Google or Facebook, he can do that. If he registered with Email and Password, I don't want him to connect to google afterwards.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem. When someone wants to register with Email and Password and the email of the user is something like `user@gmail.com`, isn't the same as a Google authentication? So what's going on in the console makes total sense, right?

Comment: When registering, nothing is happening. When the user logs in afterwards with google instead of email and password, the account gets connected.

Comment: What do you mean through "When registering, nothing is happening."? Show us what you have tried?

Comment: When registering the account stays as it should be,this means it won't connect to the google 3rd party. If you then afterwards login with Google, the account gets connected..